# Prove the inverse of the Hilbert matrix has integer entries

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

> $1 \frac{1}{2} ... \frac{1}{n}$
>
> $\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3} ... \frac{1}{n+1}$
>
> $.$
>
> $.$
>
> $.$
>
> $\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{n+1} ... \frac{1}{2n-1}$
>
> Does the inverse of this matrix have integer entries? Prove your
>   statement.

I thought of  multiplying every line $i$ by $i!$, but it leads to a very complicated solution (if it leads to a solution at all).

Source: *Linear Algebra*, Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze. Section 1.6, exercise 12.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, however, you can try for a couple of n values and see what happens. I know, it is not a proof, but maybe at least a start

Comment: Yes, it does. $\textbf{}$

Comment: Have you tried to work through the example referenced in the problem statement in more generality? (For others reading this: this reference is omitted in the question as written here, but it appears in the book.)

Comment: The reference is not important, since it's just the case when n equals 3.

Comment: @user68659 It's important in the sense that understanding it is the key to doing the exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes.

Do not dismiss the example referenced in the problem statement (the case where $n = 3$). Examples like the one I'll reproduce below help to build insight:

> Given $\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5}\end{pmatrix},\qquad$
>   $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 9 & -36 & 30 \\ -36 & 192 & -180 \\ 30 & -180 & 180 \end{pmatrix}$.

I'd suggest you explore the matrix and its inverse for $n = 4$.

What we want to show is that

$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\ \ldots & \ldots & & \ldots \\ \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \ldots & \frac{1}{2n-1}\end{pmatrix}$

is invertible and $B^{-1}$ has integer entries.

**Hints to get you started**: The matrix $B$ is known as a *Hilbert matrix* and the entries of its inverse can be represented as the product of binomial coefficients.

Comment: It is about 24 years left I read this book at my MSc (+1).

Comment: I had to brush the dust off my copy, @Babak!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU! +1

Comment: Could you add the actual proof? I think posting one using only the tools developed so far in the book would be instructive.